# Collections.sort() for LinkedList not working

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to sort a `LinkedList` based on the `Attribute` priority

### Flight Class

```
/**
 * @author Dylan
 *
 */

/**
 * A Class to hold information for flights and allow it to be manipulated
 *
 */
public class Flight {
    private String flightID;//FlightId eg(BA001)
    Integer priority; // 1 = lowest | 9 = highest

    /**
     * A simple constructor to initialise sensible values to attributes
     */
    public Flight() {
        this.setFlightID("BA378"); //initialises the attributes to sensible values
        this.setPriority(1); //initialises the attributes to sensible values
    }
    /**
     * A param constrctor to initials attributes to values of params
     * @param flightID
     * @param priority
     */
    public Flight(String flightID, Integer priority) {
        this.flightID = flightID; // Initialises flightID to the value of the param
        this.priority = priority;// initialises priority to the value of the param
    }

    /**
     * A simple method to return the flightID
     * @return
     */
    public String getFlightID() {
        return flightID; //returns flightID
    }

    /**
     * A simple method to set the flightID
     * @param flightID
     */
    public void setFlightID(String flightID) {
        this.flightID = flightID; //sets value of flightID to params
    }

    /**
     * a simple method to return the priority of the flight
     * @return
     */
    public Integer getPriority() {
        return priority;//returns priority of the flight
    }

    /**
     * a simple method to set the priority of the flight
     * @param priority
     */
    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;//sets the flight priority to value of params
    }
    /**
     * A method to turn attributes into a sensible string
     */
    public String toString() {
        return "Flight [flightID=  " + flightID + ", priority=" + priority + "]";//toString to change attributes into a string that's easy to read
    }
}
```

### PriorityFlightQueue1 Class

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class PriorityFlightQueue1 extends AbstractFlightQueue implements Comparator<Flight> {
    LinkedList<Object> flights = new LinkedList<Object>();

    public void joinQueue(Flight f) {
        flights.addLast(f);

    }

    public Object landFlight() {
        return flights.removeFirst();
    }

    public int size() {
        return flights.size();
    }

    public void clear() {
        Iterator<Object> it = flights.iterator();//Initialise iterator to it
        while(it.hasNext()) {//A While loop to check if there's another index after the current index
            flights.removeFirst();//If the condition is true then it will remove index
        }
    }

    public void display() {
        for(Object f : flights) {//for each statement
        System.out.println(f);//prints out f to console
        }

    }

    public int compare(Flight f1, Flight f2) {
        if(f1.getPriority() < f2.getPriority()){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
}
}
```

Method from `FlightTestClass`, This basically puts data into the linked list. I'm trying to sort that data with the `Collections.sort()` as you can see below

```
public void testPriorityFlightQueue1() {
        PriorityFlightQueue1    q = new PriorityFlightQueue1();

        Flight f1 = new Flight("BA001", 3);//entering flight details into the linkedlist(queue)
        Flight f2 = new Flight("NR273", 7);//entering flight details into the linkedlist(queue)
        Flight f3 = new Flight("RA291", 1);//entering flight details into the linkedlist(queue)
        Flight fref;


        showPriorityFlightQueue1(q);
        q.joinQueue(f1);
        System.out.println(f1 + " has joined the queue to land");
        showPriorityFlightQueue1(q);
        q.joinQueue(f2);
        System.out.println(f2 + " has joined the to land");
        showPriorityFlightQueue1(q);
        q.joinQueue(f3);
        System.out.println(f3 + " has joined the to land");
        showPriorityFlightQueue1(q);
        System.out.println("\n-----------------------------------------\n");    
        fref = (Flight) q.landFlight();
        System.out.println(fref + " has landed");
        showPriorityFlightQueue1(q);
        fref = (Flight) q.landFlight();
        System.out.println(fref + " has landed");
        showPriorityFlightQueue1(q);
        fref = (Flight) q.landFlight();
        System.out.println(fref + " has landed");
        showPriorityFlightQueue1(q);
        System.out.println("\n-----------------------------------------\n");

        Collections.sort(q.flights);

        showPriorityFlightQueue1(q);


    }
```

I really not sure as to why it won't sort the `LinkedList`
In Eclipse the suggestion box says:

> The method sort(List) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (LinkedList)

Then it wants me to Cast argument `q.flights` to `List<T>`.

Comment: The error message tells you that it isn't applicable for `LinkedList<Object>` because Object is the java base class and not sortable (doesn't implement comparable). If your list only contains `Flight` objects you should declare it as `LindedList<Flight>` but since that class doesn't implement comparable either you will get the same error message. You need to have your class implement comparable or supply a custom Comparator to the sort method.

Comment: I think you should first replace LinkedList<Object> .... with List<Flight> flights = new LinkedList<Flight>();.. . And afterthat, add a comparator to the Flight class.

Comment: Why do you store priority as type `Integer` instead of `int`? Do you realise this risks throwing NullPointerException?

Answer (score 2):

Create `Flight` comparators

```
public class Flight {
    private String flightID; // FlightId eg(BA001)
    Integer priority; // 1 = lowest | 9 = highest

    public static final Comparator<Flight> SORT_MAX_PRIORITY = new Comparator<Flight>() {
        @Override public int compare(Flight a, Flight b) {
            return b.priority - a.priority;
        }
    };

    public static final Comparator<Flight> SORT_MIN_PRIORITY = new Comparator<Flight>() {
        @Override public int compare(Flight a, Flight b) {
            return a.priority - b.priority;
        }
    };

    public static final Comparator<Flight> SORT_BY_ID = new Comparator<Flight>() {
        @Override public int compare(Flight a, Flight b) {
            return a.flightID.compareTo(b.flightID);
        }
    };
    // the rest of the class...
}
```

Then sort using one of them.

```
Collections.sort(q.flights, Flight.SORT_MAX_PRIORITY);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Analysis

Currently, you are trying to call the method:

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
void sort(List<T> list)
```

with the `LinkedList<Object> flights` as the argument.

Please note that the `Object` class does not implement the `Comparable<? super Object>` interface. So, this is why the compilation fails.

## Solution overview

Given, we have a class named `Entity`.

There are two different approaches to implement the comparison operation(s) for the class:

1. «Internal» comparison (see [the «Comparable type» section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)): the single comparison operation is implemented by the entity itself: the `Entity` class implements the `Comparable<? super Entity>` interface. To use this comparison operation, it is necessary to call the method:

   > `public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)`
   >
   > Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements. All elements in the list must implement the `Comparable` interface. Furthermore, all elements in the list must be mutually comparable (that is, `e1.compareTo(e2)` must not throw a `ClassCastException` for any elements `e1` and `e2` in the list).
   >
   > — [`public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void Collections.sort(List<T> list)` (Java Platform SE 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-).
2. «External» comparisons (see [the «Comparators» section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)): from one to many comparison operations that are implemented as entity comparator classes — the classes that implement the `Comparator<? super Entity>` interface. To use this comparison operation(s), it is necessary to call the method:

   > `public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`
   >
   > Sorts the specified list according to the order induced by the specified comparator. All elements in the list must be mutually comparable using the specified comparator (that is, `c.compare(e1, e2)` must not throw a `ClassCastException` for any elements `e1` and `e2` in the list).
   >
   > — [`public static <T> void Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)` (Java Platform SE 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-).

These approaches can be combined, i.e. they are not mutually exclusive.

## Minimal solution

Currently, you have defined the only one way to compare the instances of the `Flight` class and this comparison does not require any external context (just instances of the `Flight` class themselves), therefore, the minimal solution is to make the `Flight` class comparable.

1. Instead of «too-generic» representation of the flights collection (`LinkedList<Object> flights`) use the concrete one (`LinkedList<Flight> flights`).
2. Instead of having the `PriorityFlightQueue1` class as the `Comparator<Flight>` interface implementation, update the implementation of the `Flight` class to implement the `Comparable<Flight>` interface by moving the comparison here.

References:

1. [Object Ordering (The Java™ Tutorials > Collections > Interfaces), Oracle, The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand this is a study task. There is a lot can be criticized with naming, type casting and formatting. No offence, just keep it in mind for future style improvements. At least - please don't add `//comments` to the end of line, let it be single line comment.

Regarding the question:

`Collections.sort(q.flights)` requires `q.flights` to be a collection of something comparable. But in your case this is `List<Objects>`. Doesn't matter that your `Objects` are really `Flights`. List is defined as `List<Objects>`. And `Object` is not `Comparable`. And even if you'd have `List<Flight>`, your `Flights` are also not `Comparable`.

Option 1. Make your flight as `Flight implements Comparable<? super Flight>` and define your list as `List<SomethingComparable super Flight>`.

Option 2. If you want to sort anything that is not implement `Comparable`, you can use other sort method:

```
Collections.sort(List<Something> list, Comparator<? super Something>)
```

In your case `PriorityFlightQueue1` could be passed there as `Comparator<Flight>` if your list were not be the `List<Object>`.